# Поиск одинаковых классов в таблице

Tags: javascript

У меня есть таблица. Мне нужно что бы при клике на любую из ячеек все соседние элементы(и только те которые находятся рядом), которые имеют такой же рисунок(соответственно класс) поменяли цвет. Значит сделала, но очень много кода, то есть разным группам прописала разные классы, но это не правильно так как групп может быть очень много. Потом решила включить голову и как-то это сократить. Вопрос в том, как кликнув на ячейку выделить всех ее соседей с таким же классом, только те которые находятся рядом

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var blockcolor = document.getElementById('table');
  var first = document.querySelectorAll('.first');
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
  table.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.classList.contains('first')) {
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.background = 'green'
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```css
table tr th {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.background {
  background: grey;
}

.first,
.second,
.third,
.four {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.first,
.third {
  background: yellow;
}

.second,
.four {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: а в чем вопрос?)

Comment: ThisMan, спасибо забыла вопрос написать. Вопрос в том, как кликнув на ячейку выделить всех ее соседей с таким же классом и только тех которые находятся рядом

Comment: какая-то дико исковерканная задачка по работе с массивами и поиском соседей

Answer (score 2):

не в качестве ответа, но может подтолкнет к решению.

вариант на jquery

```js
$("td").click(function(){
   $(".marked").removeClass('marked');

   var c = $(this).index();
   var r = $(this).parent().index();
   var cls = $(this).attr('class');
   
   var rows = [r-1, r, r+1];
   var cols = [c-1, c, c+1];
   
   var rowMax = $("#table").find("tr").length - 1;
   var colMax = $("#table tr:first-child td").length -1;
   
   rows.forEach(function(rIdx){
       if(rIdx < 0 || rIdx > rowMax) return false;
       
       cols.forEach(function(cIdx){
           if(cIdx < 0 || cIdx > colMax) return false;
           
           var cell = $("#table tr").eq(rIdx)
                           .find("td").eq(cIdx);
                           
           if( cell.hasClass(cls) ){
               cell.addClass('marked');
           }
                      
       });
   });
   
});
```

```css
.first { background-color: pink; }
.first::after { content: '✫'; }
.second { background-color: yellow;}
.second:after {  content: '❄'; }

td { width: 40px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; }

.marked { color: red; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="first"></td>
    <td class="first"></td>
    <td class="second"></td>
    <td class="second"></td>
    <td class="second"></td>
    <td class="second"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first"></td>
    <td class="first"></td>
    <td class="second"></td>
    <td class="second"></td>
    <td class="first"></td>
    <td class="first"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first"></td>
    <td class="second"></td>
    <td class="second"></td>
    <td class="first"></td>
    <td class="first"></td>
    <td class="second"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first"></td>
    <td class="second"></td>
    <td class="first"></td>
    <td class="first"></td>
    <td class="first"></td>
    <td class="first"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Странно, но никто не додумался сделать как я, вот что значит сначала надо подумать все варианты, а не первый попавшийся строчить))

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько зачем делать как вы, если у вас выделяются не соседние элементы, а просто все элементы из кликнутой строки?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на чистом JS. Вид элемента определяется по атрибуту data-type чтобы не было конфликта с классами, это значит что можно присваивать сколько угодно и какие угодно классы. Выделяются только те которые впритык. До этого выбранные элементы не сбиваются и им можно обратно отключать активность.

```js
const th = document.querySelectorAll('th');

[...th].forEach(i => i.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  const active = target.classList.contains('active')
  const myTr = target.closest('tr')
  const myIndex = [...myTr.children].indexOf(target)
  let elements = [target, target.previousElementSibling, target.nextElementSibling]
  
  if (myTr.previousElementSibling)
    elements.push(myTr.previousElementSibling.children[myIndex])
  if (myTr.nextElementSibling)
    elements.push(myTr.nextElementSibling.children[myIndex])

  elements = elements.filter(i => i && i.dataset.type === target.dataset.type)
  
  for (i of elements) {
    i.classList.toggle('active', !active)
  }
}))
```

```css
.active {
  background: green !important;
  color: white;
}

.ceil {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

[data-type="first"] {
  background: yellow;
}

[data-type="second"] {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
    <th data-type="second" class="ceil">&#10052;</th>
    <th data-type="second" class="ceil">&#10052;</th>
    <th data-type="second" class="ceil">&#10052;</th>
    <th data-type="second" class="ceil">&#10052;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
    <th data-type="second" class="ceil">&#10052;</th>
    <th data-type="second" class="ceil">&#10052;</th>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
    <th data-type="second" class="ceil">&#10052;</th>
    <th data-type="second" class="ceil">&#10052;</th>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
    <th data-type="second" class="ceil">&#10052;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
    <th data-type="second" class="ceil">&#10052;</th>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
    <th data-type="first" class="ceil">&#10027;</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Илья, спасибо вам за решение, но суть в том что соседи не только на одной строчки, а в том что весь блок соседей нужно покрасить

Comment: Переделал, а нужно чтобы можно было делать активными много элементов или чтобы предыдущие активные элементы ставились обратно не активными?

Comment: спасибо, что на чистом js, но не то.соседи соседей тоже нужно захватить. и так получится, что выделяется весь желтый блок только с  левой стороны

Comment: @ Илья, не обязательно что бы предыдущие активные элементы обратно остановились не активными

Comment: то есть выбирать элементы как сделал teran? или вообще выбирать всех, например, если нажать на желтых слева, то они все выделяются?

Comment: ну у teran почти захватывает все элементы, которые слева и желтые, но смысл в этом

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var blockcolor = document.getElementById('table');
  var first = document.querySelectorAll('.first');
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
  table.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // элемент, на который кликнули
    const {target} = event;
    // обрабатываем только ячейки
    if(target.nodeName !== 'TH') return;
    const isActive = target.getAttribute('active')
    const className = target.classList.value;
    const parent = target.parentNode; // строчка, в которой находится ячейка
    
    // проходимся циклом по всем дочерним элементам
    for(child of parent.children) {
      if(child.classList.contains(className) && !isActive) {
        child.style.background = 'green';
        child.setAttribute('active', true);
      } else {
        child.style.background = '';
        child.removeAttribute('active');
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```css
table tr th {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.background {
  background: grey;
}

.first,
.second,
.third,
.four {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.first,
.third {
  background: yellow;
}

.second,
.four {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="second">&#10052;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
    <th class="first">&#10027;</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```